# C++ push_back an object and get pointer to the object

Tags: c++, pointers

In C++, how can I push_back an object and get pointer to the object in the vector. For example

```
vector<Item> items;
```

Then I push a new object

```
Item newItem;
items.push_back(newItem);
Item* myItem = // pointer to the pushed object in vector
```

How I keep a pointer to the object in vector?

The problem is if I use

```
const int last = items.size()-1;    
Item* myItem = &item[last];
```

Whenever a new element is added, the pointer will be broken.

Comment: `&items.back()`, but the pointer is potentially going to be invalidated at the next `push_back`. If you want pointers to elements to remain valid in spite of push_back use a deque.

Comment: If you need to keep pointers to the contents around, don't use a vector!

Answer (score 3):

If you use `push_back()` it will be the item returned by `back()`.

So you could use `Item* myItem = &items.back();`

But it is a bad idea because iterators and pointers will be invalidated whenever a vector expands.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the `back` member of `vector`, but you have no guarantees that that pointer will be valid for long. It follows an example:

```
Item newItem;
items.push_back(newItem);
Item* myItem = &items.back();
```

Another approach can be to use `shared_ptr`, even though it requires to slightly modify your code. It follow an example:

```
std::shared_ptr<Item> newItem = std::make_shared<Item>();
items.push_back(newItem);
```

In this case, `newItem` is already a *pointer* (well, not a naked one, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) for further details). The problem is that, from now on, your container actually contains pointers and I don't know if it's a viable solution or it requires you to change too much code to deal with them.

Of course, your vector won't be anymore of type `std::vector<Item>`, instead you have to use `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item>>`.